# pytorch torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes .ipynb_checkpoints

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

Tried to load training data with pytorch torch.datasets.ImageFolder in Colab.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(400),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])
dataset_path = 'ss/'
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=dataset_path, transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=20)
```

I encountered the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7abcc1f434b1> in <module>()
      2                                 transforms.ToTensor()])
      3 dataset_path = 'ss/'
----> 4 dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=dataset_path, transform=transform)
      5 dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=20)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in make_dataset(directory, class_to_idx, extensions, is_valid_file)
    100         if extensions is not None:
    101             msg += f"Supported extensions are: {', '.join(extensions)}"
--> 102         raise FileNotFoundError(msg)
    103 
    104     return instances

FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes .ipynb_checkpoints. Supported extensions are: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .ppm, .bmp, .pgm, .tif, .tiff, .webp
```

My Dataset folder contains a subfolder with many training images in png format, still the ImageFolder can't access them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when I was using IPython notebook-like tools.

First please check if there is any hidden files under your `dataset_path`. Use `ls -a` if you are under a Linux environment.

The case happen to me is I found a hidden file called `.ipynb_checkpoints` which is located parallelly to image class subfolders. I think that file causes confusion to PyTorch dataset. I made sure it is not useful so I simply deleted it. Then the dataset works fine.

Or if you would like to simply ignore that file, you may also try [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68145915110/).

Comment: It was in Colab. I don't know if we can access hidden files in Colab but I'll surely try.

Answer (score 1):

The files in the image folder need to be placed in the subfolders for each class, like this:

```
root/dog/xxx.png
root/dog/xxy.png
root/dog/[...]/xxz.png

root/cat/123.png
root/cat/nsdf3.png
root/cat/[...]/asd932_.png
```

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder

Are your files in `ss` dir organized in this way?

Comment: Yes, my images are in a subfolder of the dataset path

Comment: I guess the problem is with notebook checkpoints `Found no valid file for the classes .ipynb_checkpoints.`

Answer (score 0):

1- The files in the image folder need to be placed in the subfolders for each class (as said Sergii Dymchenko)

2- Put the absolute path when using google colab

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for google colaboratory:
When you creating a directory, coollaboratory additionally creates .ipynb_checkpoints in it.
To solve the problem, it is enough to remove it from the folder containing directories with images (i.e. from the train folder). You need to run:

```
!rm -R test/train/.ipynb_checkpoints
!ls test/train/ -a   #to make sure that the deletion has occurred
```

where `test/train/` is my path to datasets folders

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error recently. Turns out it was a directory structure issue. Personally I was using this with ImageLoader so make sure your structure looks like this. (Note I also used google colab):

data

- data_you_are_trying_to_train

  - train

    - class_1
  - test

    - class_1