# Torchvision datasets gives an error when attempting to create ImageFolder

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I'm currently tinker with a GAN and am using the dataset Safebooru.
In the repository I'm getting this code there is a download zip which contains.

```
all_data.csv
```

The csv contains the columns:

```
id,created_at,rating,score,sample_url,sample_width,sample_height,preview_url,tags
```

And all it's associated data.
I attempt to import the data like so:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
```

then the original code has the zip extracting:

```
!mkdir cartoons
!mkdir cartoons/1
!unzip -n -q /content/data/My\ Drive/cartoonGAN/safebooru.zip -d cartoons/1/ #extract to subfolder due to DataLoader needs subdirectories
```

then I try to check the ImageFolder

cartoon_dataset = ImageFolder('cartoons/', transformer)

This kicks out an error that the file is not found:

```
FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes 1. Supported extensions are: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .ppm, .bmp, .pgm, .tif, .tiff, .webp
```

I found [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229246/pytorch-torchvision-datasets-imagefolder-filenotfounderror-found-no-valid-file) referenced here but it does not help.  .ipynb_checkpoints this does not exists in my directory (I checked).

Any idea why this happens? Am I supposed to actually download the physical images and have them in the specified directory

Comment: This isn't noted in your question, but a `.csv` file is not in the allowed extension types as noted in your error. What is the contents of your `cartoons` dir? Have you tried loading the contents of the lines for `sample_url` as i'd imagine these have the correct extension to not throw the error?

Comment: cartoons directory only contains directory 1 which is created in original code (just added it).  It does extract the contents.  Do I need to extract the contents of the images? @ViaTech